# Urllib and databricks access token

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, databricks, urllib

Im trying to score user input againt a model hosted in azure databricks. For this I can only use urllib which is a standard library inside python. I did use Requests for my need and below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import requests

def create_tf_serving_json(data):
  return {'inputs': {name: data[name].tolist() for name in data.keys()} if isinstance(data, dict) else data.tolist()}

def score_model(model_uri, databricks_token, data):
  headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {databricks_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  }
  data_json = data.to_dict(orient='records') if isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame) else create_tf_serving_json(data)
  response = requests.request(method='POST', headers=headers, url=model_uri, json=data_json)
  if response.status_code != 200:
      raise Exception(f"Request failed with status {response.status_code}, {response.text}")
  return response.json()

# Scoring a model that accepts pandas DataFrames
data =  pd.DataFrame([{
  "Pclass": 1,
  "Age": 22,
  "SibSp": 1,
  "Parch": 1,
  "Fare" :50
}])
score_model("My Model URL", 'Databricks Token', data)
```

Can someone help me to do the same with urllib.

Thanks in advance!